# Why isn't my app icon showing up in the emulator or on a device?

Tags: android, android-studio, appicon

In Android Studio, my app icon is not showing up on the home screen of my emulator or on a device.

I've scoured stackoverflow for solutions and have tried everything I found: I created the Image Asset and the ic_launcher files are in all the mipmap folders (for various resolutions). I tried cleaning and rebuilding. I tried different emulators, and deleting emulators and then reinstalling them. It does show up (usually) at the top of the app when I click the Recents button and it minimizes.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.company.example.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.company.example.ViewListContents"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.company.example.AboutUs"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here are my XML ic_launcher files:

ic_launcher.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/> <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/> </adaptive-icon>`

ic_launcher_round.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/> <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/> </adaptive-icon>`

and ic_launcher_foreground file:
[ic_launcher_foreground file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV4Qt.png)

Comment: please share the code sample of ic_launcher.xml and ic_launcher_round.xml

Comment: Here it is: ic_launcher.xml: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>`

Comment: ic_launcher_round.xml: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>`

Comment: Please update your post with the xmls instead of posting them as comments. It may also be helpful to share your @mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground :)

Comment: @oemel09 Ah, okay. Edited the post.

Comment: check your project again...there should be two xml files, ic_launcher_background.xml and ic_launcher_foreground.xml...and please add them to your question... then i'm gonna summarize your problem in Sha Allah

Answer (score 0):

In your `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml` files, change the color to drawable (and i'm guessing that you haven't replaced or deleted the default `ic_launcher_background.xml` and `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` files)

```
<background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
```

to be:

```
<background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
```

But if you have deleted the files then, add below code as `ic_launcher_background.xml` in your drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
    android:height="108dp"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:viewportHeight="108"
    android:viewportWidth="108"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#008577"
          android:pathData="M0,0h108v108h-108z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M9,0L9,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,0L19,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M29,0L29,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M39,0L39,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M49,0L49,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M59,0L59,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M69,0L69,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M79,0L79,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M89,0L89,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M99,0L99,108"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,9L108,9"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,19L108,19"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,29L108,29"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,39L108,39"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,49L108,49"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,59L108,59"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,69L108,69"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,79L108,79"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,89L108,89"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M0,99L108,99"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,29L89,29"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,39L89,39"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,49L89,49"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,59L89,59"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,69L89,69"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M19,79L89,79"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M29,19L29,89"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M39,19L39,89"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M49,19L49,89"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M59,19L59,89"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M69,19L69,89"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M79,19L79,89"
          android:strokeColor="#33FFFFFF" android:strokeWidth="0.8"/>
</vector>
```

This should solve the problem. Let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I still had ic_launcher_background.xml my drawable folder so I just changed the color to drawable. Still no luck :-/